# Issue with Declarative Transactions and TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy in combination with JOOQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, jooq

I have a data source configuration class that looks as follows, with separate `DataSource` beans for testing and non-testing environments using JOOQ. In my code, I do not use `DSLContext.transaction(ctx -> {...}` but rather mark the method as transactional, so that JOOQ defers to Spring's declarative transactions for transactionality. I am using **Spring 4.3.7.RELEASE**.

I have the following issue:

- During testing (JUnit), `@Transactional` works as expected. A single method is transactional no matter how many times I use the `DSLContext`'s `store()` method, and a `RuntimeException` triggers a rollback of the entire transaction.
- During actual production runtime, `@Transactional` is completely ignored. A method is no longer transactional, and `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap()` holds two separate values: one showing to my connection pool (which is *not* transactional), and one showing the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`).
  [image]

In this case, I would have expected only a single resource of type `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` which wraps my DB CP.

- After much trial and error using the second set of configuration changes I made (noted below with "AFTER"),  `@Transactional` works correctly as expected even during runtime, though  `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap()` holds the following value:
  [image]

In this case, my `DataSourceTransactionManager` seems to not even know the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` (most likely due to my passing it the simple `DataSource`, and not the proxy object), which seems to completely 'skip' the proxy anyway.

*My question is*: the initial configuration that I had seemed correct, but did not work. The proposed 'fix' works, but IMO should not work at all (since the transaction manager does not seem to be aware of the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`).

What is going on here? Is there a cleaner way to fix this issue?

### BEFORE (not transactional during runtime)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RefreshScope
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DSLContext dslContext(org.jooq.Configuration configuration) throws SQLException {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public org.jooq.Configuration defaultConfiguration(DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider) {
        org.jooq.Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
            .derive(dataSourceConnectionProvider)
            .derive(SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_5);
        configuration.set(new DeleteOrUpdateWithoutWhereListener());
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(dataSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnClass(EmbeddedPostgres.class)
    static class EmbeddedDataSourceConfig {

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.port}")
        private int dbPort;

        @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
        public EmbeddedPostgres embeddedPostgres() throws Exception {
            EmbeddedPostgres embeddedPostgres = EmbeddedPostgresHelper.startDatabase(dbPort);
            return embeddedPostgres;
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSource dataSource(EmbeddedPostgres embeddedPostgres) throws Exception {
            DataSource dataSource = embeddedPostgres.getPostgresDatabase();
            return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnMissingClass("com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres")
    @RefreshScope
    static class DefaultDataSourceConfig {

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.url}")
        private String url;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.username}")
        private String username;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.password}")
        private String password;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.driverClass}")
        private String driverClass;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.MaximumPoolSize}")
        private Integer maxPoolSize;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @RefreshScope
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            log.debug("Connecting to datasource: {}", url);
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = buildPool();
            DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
            return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
        }

        private HikariConfig buildPool() {
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setJdbcUrl(url);
            config.setUsername(username);
            config.setPassword(password);
            config.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
            config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
            config.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);

            return config;
        }
    }
```

### AFTER (transactional during runtime, as expected, all non-listed beans identical to above)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RefreshScope
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy dataSourceProxy) {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(dataSourceProxy);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSourceProxy(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnMissingClass("com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres")
    @RefreshScope
    static class DefaultDataSourceConfig {

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.url}")
        private String url;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.username}")
        private String username;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.password}")
        private String password;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.driverClass}")
        private String driverClass;

        @Value("${spring.jdbc.MaximumPoolSize}")
        private Integer maxPoolSize;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @RefreshScope
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            log.debug("Connecting to datasource: {}", url);
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = buildPoolConfig();
            DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
            return dataSource; // not returning the proxy here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record, this question seems to have been asked on the spring boot issue tracker as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12377

Comment: Hi @LukasEder, yes, I had posted the issue there separately, though it seems to have been misplaced. I moved it to SO. My apologies for the confusion for not having mentioned the above here. Thank you for updating both this question and the tracker.

Comment: Are your classes working with the `DataSource` directly (e.g. JDBC)?  If not, I don't think you should be using `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` at all.  As stated in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html), "Note that the transaction manager, for example DataSourceTransactionManager, still needs to work with the underlying DataSource, not with this proxy."

Comment: If your code does use JDBC as well as Spring's abstractions then you will need to create two beans.  First, the plain data source, which you pass to Spring's abstractions (e.g. `DataSourceTransactionManager`) and a second bean, the proxy, which wraps the first bean and which you pass to your classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll turn my comments into an answer.

The transaction manager should NOT be aware of the proxy.  From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html):

> Note that the transaction manager, for example
>   DataSourceTransactionManager, still needs to work with the underlying
>   DataSource, not with this proxy.

The class `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` is a special purpose class that is not needed in most cases.  Anything that is interfacing with your data source through the Spring framework infrastructure should NOT have the proxy in their chain of access.  The proxy is intended for code that cannot interface with the Spring infrastructure.  For example, a third party library that was already setup to work with JDBC and did not accept any of Spring's JDBC templates.  This is stated in the same docs as above:

> This proxy allows data access code to work with the plain JDBC API and
>   still participate in Spring-managed transactions, similar to JDBC code
>   in a J2EE/JTA environment. However, if possible, use Spring's
>   DataSourceUtils, JdbcTemplate or JDBC operation objects to get
>   transaction participation even without a proxy for the target
>   DataSource, avoiding the need to define such a proxy in the first
>   place.

If you do not have any code that needs to bypass the Spring framework then do not use the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` at all.  If you do have legacy code like this then you will need to do what you already configured in your second setup.  You will need to create two beans, one which is the data source, and one which is the proxy.  You should then give the data source to all of the Spring managed types and the proxy to the legacy types.

Comment: Ah, now it all makes sense. JOOQ is 'legacy code' in the eyes of Spring in this case, hence its DB accesses must be made through the a connection provider that retrieves the connections from the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`. The second configuration implicitly gives access to the proxy object anytime the `DSLContext` is used. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: do we need TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy  for using the JDBI Framework?